# How can i add a disclosure button to a MKAnnotation?

Tags: objective-c, android-mapview, mapkit, mkannotation, disclosure

I want to add a disclosure button to a `MKAnnotation` to segue to another view.

The button should look like this one:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ivuzn.png)

Here's my **.h** and **.m** files.

---

### .h file

```
//
//  POI.h
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface POI : NSObject <MKAnnotation> {

    NSString *title;
    NSString *subtitle;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
}

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *subtitle;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;

- (id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)_coordinate title:(NSString *)_titolo andSubTitle:(NSString *)_sottotitolo;


@end
```

---

### .m file

```
//
//  POI.m

#import "POI.h"



@implementation POI

@synthesize title, subtitle, coordinate;
-(id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)_coordinate title:(NSString *)_titolo andSubTitle:(NSString *)_sottotitolo {

    [self setTitle:_titolo];
    [self setSubtitle:_sottotitolo];
    [self setCoordinate:_coordinate];



    return self;
}

@end
```

in my ViewController i call this using:

```
  pinLocation.latitude = 4.8874;
    pinLocation.longitude = 1.400;
    POI *poi = [[POI alloc] initWithCoordinate:pinLocation title:@"foo" andSubTitle:@"bar"];
    [_mapView addAnnotation:poi];
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Three steps.

1) In your header file (.h) *or* your implementation file's (.m) class extension conform to `MKMapViewDelegate`:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate> { ... }
```

2) Set your view controller as the delegate of `MKMapViewDelegate` to receive delegate callbacks. Commonly done in `viewDidLoad`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.mapView.delegate = self;
}
```

3) Implement the following delegate function to show the disclosure button:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation
{   
    MKPinAnnotationView *newAnnotation = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]     initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"pinLocation"];

    newAnnotation.canShowCallout = YES;
    newAnnotation.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];

    return newAnnotation;
}
```

the following function will assist in determining what action (in your case, presenting a view) is taken upon touching the disclosure button.

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    //launch a new view upon touching the disclosure indicator
    TestVCViewController *tvc = [[TestVCViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TestVCViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:tvc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i tried to add your code but it doesn't show nothing...

Comment: Do you currently have any points plotted? Have you declared the use of <MKMapViewDelegate> in the header file of your viewcontroller? You'll need to do this to access the MapKit delegate methods. I'll clarify this in my answer.

Comment: Yes, this is my header, thank you! [code] @interface LFViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate>   {
    
    BOOL _doneInitialZoom;
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;

    
}[code]

Comment: Ok, i solved implementing your code and adding a _mapView.delegate = self;  in - (void)viewDidLoad ,  Thank you so much!

Comment: If you are showing `userLocation`, make sure to return an `MKPinAnnotationView` with a different identifier in `if (annotation == mapView.userLocation) {`

Comment: Hey! Your answer helped me. But can you please tell me, If I have 15 pins currently showing then how can I detect which pin has been tapped on calloutAccessoryControlTapped:

Comment: @Gati if your view controller conforms to the `MKMapViewDelegate` protocol and you implement the delegate method `-mapView:annotationView:calloutAccessoryControlTapped:` (implemented above) then you should receive the callback when that control is tapped.

Comment: Yeah! That's true. I am receiving callback event when control is tapped. But I am asking how to identify which pin has been tapped? Means suppose there are 15 pins and if I pressed 5th one. Then how can I detect that I have pressed no.5 pin in -mapView:annotationView:calloutAccessoryControlTapped: method.

Comment: using above methods , i am getting multiple pins on same location and i am, having only one . then why it is showing two pins ? any idea ? and i can not see title and sub title touching on those pins . before using these methods it was showing title perfectly but now it is not . anyone knows why it is happening like this ?

Answer (score 0):

In your `- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation` method use this:

```
annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
```

where `annotationView` is the view to be returned.